# Too much spacing between StackPanel items in Windows Store app

Tags: c#, listview, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I'd like to arrange some TextBlocks horizontally without any margins. I can see that my TextBlock is as small as it should be, but for some reason a lot of space is added around it. I think it has something to do with the ListView or its styling, but I don't know what.

[image]

I have a following layout:

```
<ListView Width="Auto" SelectionMode="None" Background="#654321" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border Background="Black">
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <x:String>A</x:String>
    <x:String>B</x:String>
    <x:String>C</x:String>
    <x:String>D</x:String>
    <x:String>E</x:String>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other way to look at it - `ListView` is really designed as a control where you can tap, select, drag and otherwise interact with the items. I think if you want to remove all the features that ensure the sizes are touchable with fat fingers - you might just be better off using something like the base `ItemsControl` or `ListBox` which might not have these limitations. If you get rid of all the margins and leave your items so small - there's no point in using the `ListView` and it will just complicate things and make performance bad.

Comment: Using a ListBox is easier (and more correct) than trying to hack ListView into compliance, thanks

Answer (score 4):

What you need to change is the `ItemContainerStyle`. You can get the `Style` from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj709921.aspx).

The big thing to notice is that the default `Margin` of the `Style` is:

```
<Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,18,2"/>
```

Which explains the large gap. Change it to:

```
<Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,2"/>
```

And that should help solve your issue.

One last thing to note is that they also have a default `ContentMargin="4"` (if using the `ListViewItemsPresenter`) or a bunch of `Margin`s of 4 spread throughout the style (especially on the `Border`s), which you may need to change as well.

Comment: Great, setting the `Margin` of `ListViewItem` through `ItemContainerStyle` got rid of the margins, but the items themselvers are still too big.

Comment: Start removing things from the style definition. Firstly, there are a few transparent contents like the `PlaceholderTextBlock` which will add space you wouldn't otherwise use (like the lower portion of text on a `g`. Also, make sure you modified *all* instances of Margin and Padding that exist. It may be easier to just use a basic `ItemsControl` rather than a `ListView` in my opinion.